# Checking Google Sheets cell content via Apps Script to determine if a PDF should be exported

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf, getvalue

The script seeks to send an email to which is attached a zipfile of sheets converted to PDF files. Only sheets with content are to be included in the zip file.

```
function zipit() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[Google Key]/edit#");
// Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());  
  var print1  = ss.getSheetByName("Print1");  
  var print2A = ss.getSheetByName("Print2A");
  var print2B = ss.getSheetByName("Print2B");
  var print2C = ss.getSheetByName("Print2C");
  var print3A = ss.getSheetByName("Print3A");

//get email address to send to 
  var organiserEmail = calcSheet.getRange("E31").getValue();   

//get date range for next month
  var tablesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Next Month");
  var period = print1.getRange("V2:W2").getValue(); // period for the league taken from League 1
  var subject = "Singles League print outputs for : " + period;
  var body = "Attached are the PDF files to allow you to print the tables";

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true'                         // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    //+ '&printRange'
    + '&pagenumbers=false'                 // hide page numbers
    + '&gridlines=true'                    // hide gridlines
    + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

// Use token to access the sheet
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    }
  };


// make empty array to hold fetched blobs
  var blobs = [];
  var i=0; // Set start number of 'blobs[]'

// **league 1**
  var SheetId = '56'; // id of League 1 print sheet - 'print1'
  var filename = '1' + '.pdf';
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
    catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(filename);
    i=i+1; // Set number of 'blob'

// **League 2A**
  // Check if sheet has content
  if (print2A.getRange("A11").getValue() != null) {
    SheetId = '58'; // id of League 1 print sheet - 'print2A'
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
    catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('2A' + '.pdf');
    i=i+1; // Set number of 'blob'
  }  

// **League 2B**
  // Check if sheet has content
  if (print2B.getRange("A11").getValue() != null) {
    SheetId = '59'; // id of League 2B print sheet - 'print2B'
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
    catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('2B' + '.pdf');
    i=i+1; // Set number of 'blob'
  }     

// **League 2C**
  //Check if sheet has content
  if (print2C.getRange("A11").getValue() != null) {
    SheetId = '62'; // id of League 2C print sheet - 'print2C'
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
    catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('2C' + '.pdf');
    var i=i+1; // Set number of 'blob'
  }

// **League 3A**
  // Check if sheet has content
  if (print3A.getRange("A11").getValue() != null) {
    SheetId = '60'; // id of League 3A print sheet - 'print3A'
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
    catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('3A' + '.pdf');
    i=i+1; // Set number of 'blob'
  }

/************************************************/
// New Participants
  SheetId = '38'; // id of New Participants print sheet - 'New Participants Alpha'

  // create PDF
  // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
  try { var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options); }
  catch(err) { Browser.msgBox("Error"); }

  // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
  blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('Participants' + '.pdf');

/************************************************/
// Send email
  // create a new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
  var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName('Singles League :' + period + '.zip');

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
     GmailApp.sendEmail(organiserEmail, subject, body, {
       htmlBody: body,
       attachments:[zipBlob]     
     }); 
}
```

The idea was to print the first sheet (League 1), then move on to League 2A where Cell A11(1,11) is checked to see if there is any content... if there is content in that cell then convert the page to PDF and create a 'blob'... if no content in A11, then move to League 2B, test Cell A11 for content, if none then move to League 2C, if there is content then convert the page to PDF and create a 'blob'...and so on to the last page called Participants.
Final task is to create a zipfile and send the email with the zipfile attached.

Problem is the test of cell 'A11' doesn't work. All of the sheets (1.pdf, 2A.pdf, 2B.pdf, 2C.pdf, 3A.pdf and Participants.pdf) are in the zip file, whether or not they have no content. The email part of the routine works as it should. The Participants sheet does not print, instead there is a duplicate of 3A... 
Can anyone advise what is going on and suggest corrections?
Thanks in anticipation.

Recording below a working code to achieve the objective.... only the last part is included below:-

```
// Get token to access the sheet
   var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
   var options = {
        headers:{
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        }

        };

  var SheetId = '56'; // id of League 1 print sheet - 'print1'
  var filename = '1' + '.pdf';
// create PDF
   // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
      try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
      }
      catch(err)
      {
      Browser.msgBox("Error");
      }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

// League 2A
  // Check if sheet has content
     if ((print2A.getRange("A11").getValue())!= ""){ 
     SheetId = '58'; // id of League 1 print sheet - 'print2A'
     filename = '2A' + '.pdf';
 // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
       try {
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
       }
       catch(err)
       {
       Browser.msgBox("Error");
      }

     // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
        blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

     }  

// League 2B
  // Check if sheet has content
     if ((print2B.getRange("A11").getValue())!= ""){
     SheetId = '59'; // id of League 2B print sheet - 'print2B'
     filename = '2B' + '.pdf';

// create PDF
   // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
      try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
          }
      catch(err)
      {
      Browser.msgBox("Error");
      }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

      }     

// League 2C
  //Check if sheet has content
    if ((print2C.getRange("A11").getValue())!= ""){
    SheetId = '62'; // id of League 2C print sheet - 'print2C'
    filename = '2C' + '.pdf';

 // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
       try {
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
           }
       catch(err)
       {
       Browser.msgBox("Error");
       }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

       }

// League 3A
   // Check if sheet has content
      if ((print3A.getRange("A11").getValue())!= ""){
      SheetId = '60'; // id of League 3A print sheet - 'print3A'
      filename = '3A' + '.pdf';

// create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
       try {
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
           }
       catch(err)
          {
       Browser.msgBox("Error");
       }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

  }

// League 3B
   // Check if sheet has content
      if ((print3A.getRange("A11").getValue())!= ""){
      SheetId = '61'; // id of League 3B print sheet - 'print3B'
      filename = '3B' + '.pdf';

 // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
       try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
           }
        catch(err)
         {
       Browser.msgBox("Error");
        }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

    }

  /************************************************/
 // New Participants
    SheetId = '38'; // id of New Participants print sheet - 'New Participants Alpha'
    filename = 'Participants' + '.pdf';
  // create PDF
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
       try {
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + SheetId, options);
           }
       catch(err)
       {
       Browser.msgBox("Error");
       }

    // Convert the response to a blob and store in array
       blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename));

 /************************************************/
 // Send email
   // create a new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
      var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName('Singles League :' + period + '.zip');

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(organiserEmail, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments:[zipBlob]     
        });  
    };

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you assign to an index in the blob array, when you could just use `.push`? Consider reviewing your JavaScript truth-y and false-y behaviors, and the behavior of `getValue` vs getValues() when called on a `Range` consisting of multiple cells (such as your `period` variable). I also recommend you go through this post and reformat it to be more easily readable (highlight everything in Apps Script and press Tab to have it auto indent your code).

Comment: Have tried to reformat the code to make it more readable. No sure what you mean about .push and assigning an index in the blob array - will do some research! Also not sure about getValue vs getValues() and will research that.too.

Comment: You use `blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(filename);`, when you could ditch `i` and use `blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(filename);` - [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) appends to the end of the array (and means you can't accidentally create a sparse array, e.g. `[undefined, blob1, blob2, undefined, blob4]` will only be created if you actually insert `undefined`, while direct assignment would create it if the code where `i` is 0 or 3 isn't run).

Comment: Step 1 in your refactor is to remove the code duplication you currently have - you can create variables to hold the parameters which are altered, and then use those variables in your fixed "make a PDF" code. example: `var sheetNames = ["Print1", "Print2" ...]; sheetNames.forEach(function (name) { var sheet = wb.getSheetByName(name); var value = sheet.getRange("A11").getValue(); var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); ...`

Comment: @tehhowch - Thank you so much for your comments and advice. I now have the code working but I haven't condensed it as per your second comment... the code works and doesn't take a long time to execute... I will upload the working code shortly..